# how to set a particular value in an autoincrement column?

Tags: mysql

I used MySQL database to generate customer 'id's. These ids are referred everywhere in excel, word, and even paper documents. However, now I have to replicate our customer tables to customer tables 1, 2, 3, 4. So all replicated schemas will also have the same auto-increment column called 'id. How could I ensure that the same customers will always have the same id in different schemas? Can I insert the id to the autoincrement column?

Thanks

Comment: ...  try and let we know

Comment: One option would be to run a batch job which executes say once per day, which migrates new user records from the master table to the copy tables.  Another approach might use triggers which would insert a new user record into the other tables when an insert happens on the master table.

Comment: Why are there 4 customer tables?!?!?

Comment: Incidentally- and this is opinion only, I think it's a really bad idea to reference internal database ids. To my mind, these should have no meaning beyond the scope of the database.

Comment: @scaisEdge It looks we can still assign the particular value to an auto-increment field. But I do feel it is not safe.

Comment: @Strawberry I agree with you. But people without technology background just did this for years.